# Incorrect result when apply function to pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, cython

When I tried to apply two versions of a function, pure python vs cython, to a pandas Series, two different results are obtained

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from libc.math cimport lround

def py_func(n):
    return round(13 * n / 37)

cdef int cy_func(int n):
    return lround(13 * n / 37)

arr = np.arange(1000, 12000, 2000)

series = pd.Series(arr)
print("Original series:")
print(series)

series1 = series.apply(py_func)
series2 = series.apply(cy_func)

print("\nApplied with python function:")
print(series1)

print("\nApplied with cython function:")
print(series2)
```

The results are

```
Original series:
0     1000
1     3000
2     5000
3     7000
4     9000
5    11000
dtype: int32

Applied with python function:
0     351
1    1054
2    1757
3     688
4    1391
5     322
dtype: int64

Applied with cython function:
0     351
1    1054
2    1757
3    2459
4    3162
5    3865
dtype: int64
```

We can see that when applying the python function, we obtain incorrect results in the last three numbers. While the cython function yields the correct results.

Why does the python function produce incorrect results? And how to fix it?

**Update**

The results above were obtained on Windows 10 64-bit. However, when I tried with Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit on the same machine (using WSL), both series have the correct results. In both cases, I have `Cython==0.29, numpy==1.15.2, pandas==0.23.4`, also tested with `Cython==0.28.5, numpy==1.14.5, pandas==0.23.3`.

There's another difference in the results: with Windows 10, the `dtype` of the original series is `int32`, while the `dtype` on Ubuntu 18.04 is `int64`. The `dtype` of both result series are `int64` in both OS.

Comment: cannot reproduce with python3.6 and pandas 0.23.3.

Comment: @ead I have updated the information about the environment. The incorrect results were obtained when running on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using MinGW, `MS_WIN64` is not defined, which is used to define `SIZEOF_VOID_P` as follows in `pyconfig.h`.

```c
#if defined(MS_WIN64)
...
#   define SIZEOF_VOID_P 8
...
#elif defined(MS_WIN32)
...
#   define SIZEOF_VOID_P 4
...
#endif
```

`SIZEOF_VOID_P` is then used in `pyport.h`

```c
#ifndef PYLONG_BITS_IN_DIGIT
#if SIZEOF_VOID_P >= 8
#define PYLONG_BITS_IN_DIGIT 30
#else
#define PYLONG_BITS_IN_DIGIT 15
#endif
#endif
```

The solution is to pass `-DMS_WIN64` when compiling with MinGW.

Related [Python ticket](https://bugs.python.org/issue4709) and [discussion on cython-users group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/W1mrRkwgsxM).

Comment: actually, this is pretty important - a lot of people try to use MinGW on Windows and are not aware of this issue...